# How can file/stream serve metrics be API queried from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Let's say I push up a video to Google Drive.  I share the video link with various users, **is there a way to obtain the # of bytes served, and by whom or of some unique ID?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this data is not available from the API. Of course if you are downloading and serving the files through your app, you can generate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, not wanting to proxy it through an app rather grant Drive directly per user.